# Mysql - Search time range in datetime column

Tags: php, mysql

I need to return records from a table where a column `date_opened` (datetime) is in a specific time range irrespective of what the date is. I currently have this

```
SELECT * FROM packages WHERE HOUR(date_opened) = 9
```

but I need to drill down further. I need the results from when `date_opened` is between 09:00 and 09:30. How can I achieve this?

**Edit**
Didn't think anyone would ask for data for this but here it is:

```
CREATE TABLE `packages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_opened` datetime NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `packages` (`id`, `user`, `date_opened`) VALUES
(58, 3, '2019-08-26 09:43:25'),
(73, 3, '2019-08-30 09:43:48'),
(76, 3, '2019-09-03 09:46:33'),
(77, 3, '2019-09-03 09:57:34'),
(79, 3, '2019-09-04 09:46:58'),
(86, 3, '2019-09-06 09:34:13'),
(88, 3, '2019-09-09 09:42:08'),
(90, 3, '2019-09-11 09:42:04'),
(91, 3, '2019-09-12 09:40:05'),
(92, 3, '2019-09-12 09:59:31'),
(93, 3, '2019-09-13 09:56:12'),
(95, 3, '2019-09-16 09:41:44'),
(101, 3, '2019-09-19 09:52:01'),
(104, 3, '2019-09-20 09:54:20'),
(107, 3, '2019-09-23 09:37:47'),
(108, 3, '2019-09-24 09:25:07'),
(110, 3, '2019-09-25 09:25:46'),
(113, 3, '2019-09-26 09:42:42'),
(114, 3, '2019-09-27 09:50:44'),
(115, 3, '2019-09-30 09:25:16'),
(117, 3, '2019-10-03 09:42:21'),
(123, 3, '2019-10-10 09:25:08'),
(126, 3, '2019-10-14 09:50:07'),
(127, 3, '2019-10-15 09:55:12'),
(129, 3, '2019-10-16 09:48:47');

ALTER TABLE `packages`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `user` (`user`);
```

Desired result:

```
| id  | user | date_opened         |
| --- | ---- | ------------------- |
| 108 | 3    | 2019-09-24 09:25:07 |
| 110 | 3    | 2019-09-25 09:25:46 |
| 115 | 3    | 2019-09-30 09:25:16 |
| 123 | 3    | 2019-10-10 09:25:08 |
```

Comment: Question updated

Comment: And desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
  from packages 
 where time(date_opened) between '09:00:00' AND '09:30:00';
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i1Sb7zkYf9izia17B5tLHE/0

There's an argument for storing time again, separately from datetime, but it's possible that 8.0 has a smarter way of indexing times and dates; I'm not sure.

Comment: That works. Thanks. I'll research your point about seperate columns